# Store multiple outputs in one table

Tags: r

I am trying to store different outputs in one table so I can perform further analysis on them. below is my code where I need to run 4 times (for each company stocks). How can I store all value from the 4 companies in one table.

```
tapply(Ford_R_ER, as.integer(gl(length(Ford_R_ER), 12, length(Ford_R_ER))), FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
tapply(GE_R_ER, as.integer(gl(length(GE_R_ER), 12, length(GE_R_ER))), FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
tapply(MICROSOFT_R_ER, as.integer(gl(length(MICROSOFT_R_ER), 12, length(MICROSOFT_R_ER))), FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
tapply(ORACLE_R_ER, as.integer(gl(length(ORACLE_R_ER), 12, length(ORACLE_R_ER))), FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: if the tables have the same structure, then you can do `rbind` to bind their rows.

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple columns, use `summarise` with `across` - create a data.frame/tibble with the vectors (assuming they are of the same length), create the grouping column with `gl` and `summarise` `across` the numeric columns to get the `mean` by group

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
   group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 12, n()))) %>%
   summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(.~ grp, data = transform(df, 
   grp = as.integer(gl(nrow(df), 12, nrow(df)))),
       mean, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = NULL)
```

---

In case we have different `length`s for the vectors, create a function and reuse it

```
f1 <- function(vec, n = 12) {
     tapply(vec, as.integer(gl(length(vec), n, length(vec))), FUN = 
        mean, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

and then run the function either on a single vector or a `list` of vectors

```
f1(Ford_R_ER)
lapply(list(Ford_R_ER = Ford_R_ER, GE_R_ER = GE_R_ER, 
    MICROSOFT_R_ER = MICROSOFT_R_ER, ORACLE_R_ER = ORACLE_R_ER), f1)
```

#### data

```
dat <- data.frame(Ford_R_ER, GE_R_ER, MICROSOFT_R_ER, ORACLE_R_ER)
```